# Possible to clustering low dimensional data in constant memory?

Tags: javascript, data-mining, cluster-analysis

I'm looking to cluster some very low dimensional (2 or 3) data, into a small amount of clusters (< 25). The amount of instances I have is extremely large (order of 100M+ ). I can stream this data from the database (and potentially re-stream this for each pass) -- but want to avoid bringing the whole collection into memory. [And if I have to bring it into memory, I would like it to be as memory efficient as possible]

I'm looking for an algorithm (and ideally a Javascript implementation) that meets these requirements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at **MacQueens k-means** algorithm, which works well with streaming data, and is trivial to implement.

Oh, and it has been around since the 60s or so.

But also note that you might as well just run it on a representative sample of your data set. Most likely, the result will not be substantially different. Volume doesn't change statistical things such as means a lot.